# Silverlight and Async CTP

Tags: .net, silverlight, async-await

I have downloaded the newest version and all went well. When I go to reference the AsyncCtpLibrary_Silverlight.dll for my silverlight app it shows an error missing AsyncCtpLibrary.dll reference? The other thing I noticed was the timestamp was not today's on the files, but rather the last time I downloaded. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using the "Async Targeting Pack for Visual Studio 2012" NuGet package? (http://10rem.net/blog/2012/05/22/using-async-and-await-in-silverlight-5-and-net-4-in-visual-studio-11-with-the-async-targeting-pack) Or "Visual Studio Async CTP" (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983)

Comment: Are you using VS 2012? If you do, could you try using [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) instead?

Comment: I am using VS2010 Pro and Silverlight 5. Not using NuGet package - would be interested in this since I would like to use NuGet in the future.

Comment: I have NuGet up and running.

Comment: I have downloaded the latest version, still says missing AsyncCtpLibrary.dll???